# I need to open dialog box on linkbutton click using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

Hi i need to display dialog box on linkbutton click in asp.net.On this dialog there will be file upload control to browse files.
Can you please suggest me any example.Because i am pretty new in development.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, The way you must do is :

1) create a page that has a File Upload control inside it (name it for exmaple MyDialogPage.aspx)

and in code behind

```
protected void btn1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//do ur stuff with file 
}
```

2) on the Calling page do this:

```
<asp:LinkButton Id="callDiag" runat="server" onClientClick="CalljavascriptFunction();return false"/>
```

3) write this javascript function on the Calling page:

```
<script>
function CalljavascriptFunction()
{
          var url="MyDialogPage.aspx";
      var retval = window.showModalDialog(url, window, "center:yes;dialogWidth:800px;dialogHeight:600px");
}
</script>
```

regards

Comment: there isnt Dialog Box in asp.net as far as I know unléss you use Telerik or Jquery maybe?!! I dont know I just gave you what I'm currently using in my production project , plus the Code is for modal window so its the best Dialog that you can get coz it greys out the background just as the Form Dialog works